# when does the square root of covariance matrix equals to itself

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

In other words, under what situation of $A$, $\sqrt{A^T A} = A$?
Since in general, a matrix has several square roots, then probably a more meaningful question is that when $A$ is one of the solutions to $\sqrt{A^TA}$?

A PSD $A$ with $A^T=A$ is sufficient, I don't know if it is also necessary.

And hopefully, the answer could come with some reasoning.

Comment: Is $A$ even a square matrix?

Comment: @TedShifrin It has to be, isn't it? But I think being square is not sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $\sqrt{\cdot}$ refers to the positive semidefinite square root of a positive semidefinite matrix, $A$ must be a positive semidefinite (real) symmetric matrix.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it does refer to positive semidefinite square root, within my knowledge, I thought that's a widely accepted notation. Do you think the reverse is also true? I feel like so because this answer is almost the definition.

Comment: Yes, of course it is necessary: $A = \sqrt{A^T A}$ is positive semidefinite and symmetric.